# Update Twitter status with media with Twitter Async

Tags: php, twitter

Any idea how one would update a user's Twitter status with an image - using the [Twitter-Async](http://www.jaisenmathai.com/articles/twitter-async-documentation.html) class?

This is what I have

```
$twitter = new Twitter(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,$_SESSION['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
$array = array('media[]' => '@/img/1.jpg','status' => $status);

$twitter->post('/statuses/update_with_media.json', $array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to @billythekid, I have managed to do this. This is what you need to do:
Look these functions up in the EpiOAuth file and see what I've added and alter it where necessary.

**EpiOAuth.php**

```
//I have this on line 24
  protected $mediaUrl       = 'https://upload.twitter.com';

//and altered getApiUrl() to include check for such (you may wish to make this a regex in keeping with the rest?)
  private function getApiUrl($endpoint)
  {
    if(strpos($endpoint,"with_media") > 0)
      return "{$this->mediaUrl}/{$this->apiVersion}{$endpoint}";
    elseif(preg_match('@^/(trends|search)[./]?(?=(json|daily|current|weekly))@', $endpoint))
      return "{$this->searchUrl}{$endpoint}";
    elseif(!empty($this->apiVersion))
      return "{$this->apiVersionedUrl}/{$this->apiVersion}{$endpoint}";
    else
      return "{$this->apiUrl}{$endpoint}";
  }

// add urldecode if post is multiPart (otherwise tweet is encoded)
  protected function httpPost($url, $params = null, $isMultipart)
  {
    $this->addDefaultHeaders($url, $params['oauth']);
    $ch = $this->curlInit($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    // php's curl extension automatically sets the content type
    // based on whether the params are in string or array form
    if ($isMultipart) {
        $params['request']['status'] = urldecode($params['request']['status']);
    }

    if($isMultipart)
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params['request']);
    else
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->buildHttpQueryRaw($params['request']));
    $resp = $this->executeCurl($ch);
    $this->emptyHeaders();

    return $resp;
  }
```

**Post image**

```
// how to post image
$twitter = new Twitter(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,$_SESSION['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
$array = array('@media[]' => '@/img/1.jpg','status' => $status);

$twitter->post('/statuses/update_with_media.json', $array);
```